# Отображение картинки из директории assets

Tags: android, xml, activity, android-assets

Пытаюсь разобраться, как вывести картинку из папки assets. Прописал код в отдельном классе :

```
public class AssetsUtil {

public static Drawable loadDrawable(AssetManager manager, String fileName)
{
    try{
        InputStream in = manager.open(fileName);
        return Drawable.createFromStream(in, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}


public static String loadText(AssetManager manager, String fileName)
{
    byte[] buffer = null;
    try{
        InputStream in = manager.open(fileName);
        int size = in.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        in.read(buffer);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new String(buffer);
}
```

}

Затем прописал в Main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.picture);

    Drawable drawable = AssetsUtil.loadDrawable(getAssets(),"favorites.png");
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

}

Но почему-то картинка не отображается в XML-файле. Или она и не должна тут отображаться и отобразится после запуска на экране смартфона ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы грузите её программно, а не задаёте в разметке, Android Studio не настолько умная, чтобы подставить её.

В разметке можно так указать:

```
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:src="@mipmap/favorites"
      android:scaleType="center"/>
```

Comment: т.е. сам код правильно написан ?

Comment: выглядит правильно

Comment: Только использование данного способа не очень удобно, т.к. не видишь саму картинку, и нужно будет после каждого запуска исправлять.

Comment: Я вообще первый раз с этим сейчас знакомлюсь, т.к хочу сделать более правильную иерархию в студии, чтобы было удобней работать.

Comment: Добавил код, только вам картинку нужно перенести в папку mipmap

Comment: А вы можете дать совет, что лучше хранить в директории assets? Картинки, тексты и т.д. ?

Comment: Какие-либо бинарные файлы, да теоретически это может быть текст, но не имеет смысл записывать туда названия, потому что есть тот же strings.xml. Однако если вы решите записать 3-4 книги, то конечно лучше их положить в assets. Также там обычно хранят музыку, видео и т.п.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87953/discussion-between-programmer-and-komdosh).